# How to wait for an animation to complete with watir-webdriver?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have a test scenario which have to click on an element displayed after an animation, but element is not available for action while it is animated: `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Element is not clickable at point (...)`.

Is there a way to synchronize on the animation completion to have deterministic behavior *(I will avoid sleep-based solutions)*.

Comment: I tried but the problem was elsewhere... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution to that: in fact, we use Tweeter Bootstrap, and animations are realized through CSS properties.

The "better" way to get out of this was to wait until CSS property had its final value.

```
Watir::Wait.until {
    top = browser.execute_script 'return $("#my-id").css("top");'
    top == "30%"
}
```

Any "yet better" idea is welcome.